# Is there a way to call Flutter web platform native code?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html, dart2js

is there an approach to have something like a method channel on Flutter web apps to call to the javascript host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  JS Interop apparently works fine.  Some of the pub packages use it to link flutter web with native JS libs.  I think the early firebase packages worked that way as well.  Details linked from https://dart.dev/web/js-interop.